Regex to find match if a colon exists between double curly brackets {{key:value}}
I am trying to refactor the method below to use regex instead of indexOf:
hasMatch(value: any): boolean {
    if (isDefined(value)) {
      const valueStr = JSON.stringify(value);
      return valueStr.indexOf('{{') > -1 && valueStr.indexOf(':') > -1;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

Currently it simply checks if there are double brackets "{{" and a colon in the string. This flags for matches on colons outside of the replacement strings, which I don't want to replace.
I need to only return a match if a colon exists between two double brackets with key/value pairs like: {{key:value}}
Here is what I've cobbled together using some examples here (I'm obviously a complete regex newb):
const matches = valueStr.match(/\{{({^\}{}*)}}/g).map(x => `[${x.replace(/[^:]/g, '')}]`)

But I'm currently stuck on this error:
main.js:66071 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')

You can use a regex that matches a colon between {{ (both brackets need to be escaped with \) and }}, with optional non-} characters in between:


const valueStr = "{{key: value}}"
console.log(valueStr.match(/\{\{[^}]*:[^}]*}}/) != null)




Depending on the allowed characters for the key and value and the key and value can not be empty strings:
{{\s*\w+\s*:\s*\w+\s*}}

Regex demo
Or a more strict version without matching whitepace chars:
{{\w+:\w+}}

Regex demo
To match a key and a value, where the key and the value are not one of { } :
{{[^{}:]*[^\s{}:][^{}:]*:[^{}:]*[^\s{}:][^{}:]*}}

The pattern matches:

{{ Match literally
[^{}:]* Match optional chars other than { } :
[^\s{}:] Match a non whitespace character other than { } :
[^{}:]* Match optional chars other than { } :
: Match a colon
[^{}:]*[^\s{}:][^{}:]* The same pattern as before the colon
}} Match literally

Regex demo


const regex = /{{[^{}:]*[^\s{}:][^{}:]*:[^{}:]*[^\s{}:][^{}:]*}}/;
[
  "{{key:value}}",
  "{{ key : value }}",
  "{{ke#$%$%y:val#!$#$^$%^$%^^%$*&%ue }}",
  "{{:}}",
  "{{key:}}",
  "{{key: }}",
  "{{:value}}",
  "{{key:value:test}}"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`)
)




You can use the following function to accomplish this (my console didn't recognize your function syntax).
const hasMatch = function (s) {
    return s.match(/\{\{([^:]*):([^:}]*)\}\}/) != undefined;
}

Here's an explanation of the regex since you said you're new to it.
^      // start of input
\{\{   // find two { in a row
[^:]*  // find zero or more characters not found between [^ and ]
:      // find a colon
[^:}]* // find zero or more characters not found between [^ and ]
\}\}   // find two } in a row
$      // end of input

hasMatch("{{key:value}}")  // true
hasMatch("{{:}}")          // true
hasMatch("{{key:va:lue}}") // false (extra colon)
hasMatch("{{key value}}")  // false (no colon separator)
hasMatch("{{key,value}}")  // false (no colon separator)
hasMatch("{{key:value}")   // false (only one leading curly brace)
hasMatch("{key:value}}")   // false (only one trailing curly brace)
hasMatch("{{}}")           // false (no colon separator)

Notes:

This regex assumes the value does not contain }.
If your keys and values are guaranteed to be characters only, you can use \w* instead of [^:]* and [^:}]*.
If your keys/values need to include whitespace, use [^:\s]* and [^:\s}]*.
If your keys and values cannot be empty, replace * with +.
In JSON format, the key and value would be surrounded in quotation marks. This function will still recognize them in that case.


you can use {{([^:]+):([^}]+)}} regular expression to get key-value pair, key and value in three separate group.


const groups = "{{key: value}}".match(/\{\{([^:]+):([^}]+)\}\}/);
console.log(groups);



